# where can I get3D screen savers for ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: screensaver, gnome-screensaver

I want 3D screen saver for Ubuntu 12.04. where and how can I get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install xscreensaver-gl`

There should be some 3D screen savers in there. However I recommend against it. 3D screensavers will consume more resources then normal screensavers, and today, most systems do not benefit from a screensaver at all. Our screens simply no longer need saving.

http://www.howtogeek.com/128644/htg-explains-why-screen-savers-are-no-longer-necessary/

Is a high level view of why. But if you want something pretty to run up your electric bill or kill your battery, xscreensaver-gl will do the trick.